# Polar dielectrics

Tags: dielectric, dipole

Will polar dielectrics have greater dielectric constant than a non polar dielectric?
I think there is a direct proportionality between polarity and dielectric constant. 
Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

In general your statement is true, but it will depend on whether the axis of polarization can be aligned by the electric field. A polar substance with rigidly-held molecules in a lattice may not have a very high dielectric constant (polarizability) - but in a liquid, polar molecules will easily align and result in high polarization.

Note that the above applies at DC - at higher frequencies, the speed with which the polarization can align becomes important; consequently, I suspect that at optical frequencies the difference will mostly disappear.

Answer (score 0):

All useful dielectrics are made of some polar molecules. Without the polar dielectric no energy can be stored in an electric field in a capacitor. So if a dielectric has a higher polarity it may have a higher dielectric constant which means it can store more energy in an Electric field. Here is a link with more info.

http://byjus.com/physics/dielectric-material-and-dipole-moment/

Comment: No, energy can be stored in electric field even in vacuum. What the dielectric does is decrease electric field between the capacitor plates, so much more charge can be separated and more energy can be stored with the same potential difference.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Polarizability in the frequency range]

You are correct in the sense that polarization and relative permittivity (another name for "dielectric constant", which is not necessarily constant for reasons I will briefly explain).

The relation between polarization and relative permittivity $\epsilon (\omega)$ is given by the constitutive equation:

$P(\omega) = \epsilon (\omega) E (\omega)$

Without loss of generality, $\epsilon (\omega)$ can be separated into a real and an imaginary part $\epsilon (\omega) = \epsilon'(\omega) + i \epsilon''(\omega)$, which are important to understand why there will be frequency ranges where the polarization will be more or less strong.

If you look at the relative permittivity plot in frequency that I put above, you will see that there are specific peaks of the blue plot of $\epsilon''(\omega)$ where some peaks are found. These are matched above with ionic, dipolar, atomic and electronic polarizations, where the polarization has resonant absorption peaks (here I am not 100% sure you can just call the absorption peaks resonant but I think this is the core reason why the absorption occurs. In the literature I don't see anything that leads to think the contrary, though).

Therefore:

Polarity in dielectrics will depend heavily on its ionic, atomic and electronic structure.

If you are thinking more about the polarity regarding chemical polarity, that is outside of my area of expertise so I cannot give further information if there is a tight correlation between that parameter and more physical effects.